# How to use AppLinkData.FetchDeferredAppLinkData in Xamarin Android to deep link?

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, deep-linking, facebook-sdk-4.0

I cannot find ANY documentation about `Xamarin.Facebook.AppLinks.AppLinkData.FetchDefferredAppLinkData`. I need to reference a deep link to an uninstalled app, to run when the app is installed.

My goal is to send a reference about who indicated, sending the indicator code as a parameter to the application when started for the first time.

I'm trying to get this working in Xamarin.Forms, but I will be happy with just the implementation in Android and can create the Interface for Xamarin.Forms after.